# What's the equation for frustrated total internal reflection?

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction

Could someone provide an equation for calculating frustrated internal reflection?  Like for a partially reflective laser mirror or a beam splitter.  I believe that it depends on the refractive indexes of a first medium and a third medium if a second medium separating the two (like a mirror) is thin enough that evanescent wave coupling allows light to be transmitted through to the third if it's in a certain angle range.  However, I couldn't find an equation to calculate this.  I found one for total internal reflection but not for this.  I could use some help on this, or otherwise something that explains this.  Thank you.

Comment: Try googline "Frustrated total internal reflection". I am not sure an equation is what you want. Probably more an explanation of what it is and what it is good for. See http://www.physics.ohio-state.edu/~dws/class/570/notes/p036.pdf

Comment: See [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/322118/26076). In my answer, I derive an equation  for power transmitted by frustrated total internal reflexion

Comment: This could also help : https://www.photonics.ethz.ch/fileadmin/user_upload/Courses/NanoOptics/foundations.pdf p.23

Comment: David, could you help me clarify something in the paper you linked? Are the angles theta_3 and theta_1 equal in figure 2.7? The equation provided above the picture doesn't allow for the calculation of theta_3

Answer (score 1):

Frustrated total reflection obviously means that the usual total reflection at a surface to a medium with lower refractive index $n$ becomes less than total because the thickness of the lower $n$ medium becomes comparable to the evanescent wave damping length penetrating the lower $n$ medium.

This can be calculated by using the Fresnel equations with multiple surfaces. See [Fresnel equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations#Multiple_surfaces)